# The origin of $\int$

Tags: integration

I am recalling the first day of integration class. The teacher taught us some history about how the particular symbols came into play.
Let $y = f(x)$.
Here is how he broke up $\int_a^b y$ $dx$:
Draw two lines $x = a$ and $x = b$ and the polynomial $y = f(x)$.
The area between the three equations and $x$-axis is the area that can be found using $\int_a^b y$ $dx$.
Now split up the lines into rectangular strips of width $dx$. The integral is actually now the sum of the products of the lengths and $dx$. So it can be shown as $\Sigma_{x=a} ^b y$ $dx$.
And he said that the integral sign is found by stretching (?) $\Sigma$ to $\int$.
It did help me understand integration but the previous sentence went over my head. Is it true or was it a harmless prank by my teacher?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it is just an elongated $S$ .  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299127/what-is-this-symbol-int-called)

Comment: That is what I originally thought. But what does that $S$ represent?

Comment: S stands for sum

Comment: Oh! I did not find the linked post in the tab for related posts. So I am sorry if this is a duplicate post. Sincere apologies to everyone.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol

Comment: Thanks everyone. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Btw, the $\sum$ symbol is a Greek uppercase Sigma and stands for sum, too. I tell my students that $\sum f(x_i)\Delta x_i$ with all its sharp edges stands for the discrete Riemann sum, which in the limit becomes the nice smooth $\int f(x) dx$. (This is of course made up, but it's a good mnemonic I think. Maybe that is what your teacher was getting at as well.)

Comment: That is very neat and helps your students a lot :)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg my teacher once told me that differentiation is an integral part of mathematics. I think this will also help your students ;)